# Multithreading within entity framework context

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I have a fairly large query I want to execute in multiple threads to maximize performance.  Here is a generalization of my code:

```
public ActionResult ControllerAction()
{
    using(var context = new DataEntities())
    {
        var person = context.People.First(p => p.UserId == User.Identity.UserId);
        var model = new PersonViewModel(person);
        return View(model);
    }
}

// Inside the PersonViewModel class

public List<ApplicationViewModel> Applications { get; set; }
public List<MessageViewModel> Messages { get; set; }

public PersonViewModel(Person person)
{
    var applicationsThread = new Thread(PopulateApplications);
    applicationThread.Start(person);
    var messagesThread = new Thread(PopulateMessages);
    messagesThread.Start(person);
    // Other code to be done while application/messages threads run
    applicationThread.Join();
    messagesThread.Join();
}

private void PopulateApplications(object personObject)
{
    var person = personObject as Person;
    Applications = person.Applications.Where(/*logic*/);
}

private void PopulateMessages(object personObject)
{
    var person = personObject as Person;
    Messages = person.Messages.Where(/*logic*/);
}
```

However, when I hit that controller action, only Applications are populated.  I am guessing this has something to do with trying to access properties of the entity context object from multiple threads, but none of these threads should be colliding with each other.  The hypothesis is strengthened by the fact that switching the thread order causes Messages to be populated but Applications will remain unpopulated.

Edit, Here is the updated version using krillgar's answer:

```
private static async void GenerateAbilities(int personId)
{
using (var context = new BattleGameEntities())
{
    var personAbilities = await context
        .persons
        .First(p => p.personId == personId)
        .Messages
        .OrderBy(m => m.Date).Select(a => new MessageViewModel
        {
            //Logic 
        }).ToListAsync();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. The underlying cause of this is the fact that DbContext operates on DataReader. Only one of those can be open at a time.

If you're using .NET 4.5 and EF 6, then you can use the new `Async()` methods to automatically use multiple threads for all of that. Basically it's just a suffix on any of the methods. [Here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/async-processing.aspx) is an article on using these new methods.

```
var applications = context.Applications.ToListAsync();
var messages = context.Messages.ToListAsync();
```

If you're using .NET 4.0, then you'd have to create a new Context in each thread, and maintain them separately. At that point, you'll also run into issues where the objects are coming from separate contexts.

Yes, I know the article is in VB.NET, but the syntax is similar. For whatever reason, that's what all their articles are written in.

Comment: Note that a single context can only have one concurrent async action working against it as of EF 6. Async doesn't get you multiple threads, it gets you responsiveness. You will need multiple context instances for multiple concurrent reads.

Comment: I am using EF6.0 and am targeting the 4.5 framework (NuGet confirms that I have the latest version of EF referenced the project in question) but I don't see an exposed `ToListAsync()` method.  I'll update my post to indicate what is going on.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I did not know that. Thanks. I hadn't used that yet as we're still using VS2010 at work.